# Open Google Maps view inside iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

So basically I want to add navigation to my app, but I don't want to launch the Google Maps app for iOS and then return the user to my app, but I want to open up the navigation inside a `ViewController`, much like you can do with regular maps using `MapViews` for Google Maps.

Is this possible? I can only find resources on how to launch the Google Mapps app for iOS outside your own app, and it's not exactly the best sentence to search for either.

Just thought of a possible solution: Open the Google Maps Navigation from the Web in `WebView`...should work, right?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://cocoapods.org/?q=map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that, if you really need to use Google Maps; however, this will probably look bad. A MKMapView is much easier to use, but it uses Apple's maps. If you want to use it, take a look at the [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) and [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008210) frameworks.

Comment: Ah okay, well I don't have to use Google Maps. Might even be better to use MKMapView instead since Apple's maps is installed on the phone from the start. Good point, will look into it. Thanks for the quick response :)!

Edit: I'll mark your answer as the correct one since you indirectly stated that it was not possible unless done in a webview and directed me towards something that might be what I'm looking for instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Google Maps in your app, just implement Google Maps iOS SDK.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: I have installed google maps in my app, but I want directions with it. Which doesn't seem to work. The only instructions I can find (on your link) is how to trigger the google maps app to open up and start directions. But I want the directions inside my own app, not trigger another app.

Comment: @ClockWise it's possible to draw directions also. http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Comment: Hmm, well I don't want to draw directions on a map, I want to start the GPS function. I want the user to be at one address, and start the GPS towards another. Might not even be possible with MapKit though, I think I confused everyone by saying "directions", sorry about that.